# How to analyze a stream of multicast messages?

Tags: streaming, multicast, alerts

What technology could be used to analyze a stream of messages being multicast to a group/port ?

On receiving the messages some analysis needs to be done to create near-real time alerts should there be messages with a certain identifier for a given severity of type critical or alert etc.

The rate of messages could be of the order of a few 1000's per minute.

Comment: Err, a multicast client? Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of TCP dump to capture the multicast traffic.
eg.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -vv net 224.0.0.0/4
```

Comment: The intention is to analyze the content and say raise an alert if say the count of messages with say an identifier X is > n within the last 1 minute. There isn't a real need to store the messages since another application could be storing the message to a database or logging to a file.

Comment: what would the identifier be, and IP address? If that was the case you could add the -n option. Then it would be a case of analysing the tcp dump and raise an alarm if your threshold is met

Comment: The identifier would be a field within the multicast message(just a stream of say comma separated fields). This is not at all big-data but I am looking for suggestions on an architectural solution using streaming data design patterns.